# Yes/No :number of element of order $p$ is $ p^2 +1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Determine the  number  of element of order $p$ in $\mathbb{Z_{p^2}} \times \mathbb{Z_{p^2}}$?

My attempt :  number  of element of order $p$ in $\mathbb{Z_{p^2}} \times \mathbb{Z_{p^2}}= \frac{(p^2)^2-1}{ p^2-1}= p^2+1$

Is its  true ?

Comment: How did you get the RHS $\frac{p^4 - 1}{p^2-1}$? Is it from some formula?

Comment: ya@астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  from the   formula of $\mathbb{Z_p} \times \mathbb{Z_p} = p+1$

Comment: But jasmine, I am confused : in $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$ I see more than $4$ elements of order $3$. In fact, every element which is not $(0,0)$ has order $3$. For example, take $(1,2)$. Note that $3 \times (1,2) = (0,0)$ but $(1,2) \neq (0,0)$. This is true of any non-zero element. Kindly alleviate my confusion.

Comment: The better way to put this is that every element in $Z_{p} \times Z_p$ has order $1$ or $p$ because anything added to itself $p$ times gives $(0,0)$ and the order of any element must then divide $p$. But only one element has order $1$, the identity, so every other element has order $p$. Something similar has to be done for $Z_{p^2} \times Z_{p^2}$.

Comment: okss @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг   but  u can see the chapter $8$. $Q.63$ Gallian books  and supplementary excercise  Q.53  chapter 8  gallian  books this problem  is there

Comment: I will have a look, thanks. Having said that, the answer below is satisfactory for me.

Answer (score 4):

You have not shown enough details.

Let $p=|(a,b)|=\text{lcm}(a,b), a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}.$ This is equivalent to $|a|,|b|\in \{1,p\}$ excluding the case $a=b=e,$ so we have $p^2 - 1$ such elements.

Answer (score 4):

No.  It's $p^2-1$, because $\Bbb Z_{p^2}×\Bbb Z_{p^2}$ contains a subgroup $\Bbb Z_p×\Bbb Z_p$.

On the other hand, if $(a,b)$ has order $p$, then $a,b\in\Bbb Z_p$.  That is, $(a,b)\in\Bbb Z_p×\Bbb Z_p$.